# Php: Output a delimited text file to HTML table rows

Tags: php

I have a text file with a list of semicolon-delimited items. I'd like for each semicolon to create a new HTML tr. In addition, I would like for commas within the semicolon-delimited items to separate the item into columns (td). The table would have three columns.

How can this be done with php?

Comment: What part of this is confusing? The PHP features needed are all very basic: `explode` to split the string, and `for` to loop over the resulting arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be:

```
$input = "1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9";

echo "<table>\n<tr><td>".str_replace(array(",", ";"), array("</td><td>", "</td></tr>\n<tr><td>"), $input)."</td></tr></table>";
```

Result:

```
<table>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Awesome thanks MartyIX and everyone else that replied. I was able to get it working thanks to your help.

Answer (score 1):

---

### Standard approach

Start by splitting your strings... Let's say you have:

```
$str = 'text, something, value; another, extra, thing; string, content, data';
```

**Note**: you can read the file with with [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

Now you can use [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) on it to get the parts:

```
$rows = explode(';', $str);
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $cells = explode(',', $row);
    //....
}
```

And output:

```
$rows = explode(';', $str);
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    $cells = explode(',', $row);
    foreach ($cells as $cell)
    {
        echo '<td>'.$cell.'</td>'
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    echo "\n"; // just for presentation
}
```

That would yield:

```
<tr><td>text</td><td>something</td><td>value</td></tr>
<tr><td>another</td><td>extra<td><td>thing</td></tr>
<tr><td>string</td><td>content<td><td>data</td></tr>
```

---

### str_getcsv

From PHP 5.3 and above you can do use [str_getcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php):

```
$rows = str_getcsv($str, ';');
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    $cells = str_getcsv(',', $row);
    foreach ($cells as $cell)
    {
        echo '<td>'.$cell.'</td>'
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    echo "\n"; // just for presentation
}
```

The adventage of using `str_getcsv` is that it allows you to specify `eclosure` and `escape` characters. For example:

```
$str = '"text", "something", "value"; "another", "look: \"escape sequence\"";
```

There the `enclosure` character is `"` and the `escape` character is `\`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = file("your_file.txt");
foreach ($data as $line) {
    $trs = explode(";", $line);
    foreach ($trs as $tr) {
        echo '<tr>';
        $tds = explode(",", $tr);
        foreach ($tds as $td) {
            echo '<td>';
            echo $td;
            echo '</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `explode` function (http://www.php.net/explode) then loop through the result/s and echo it out in a table.

Comment: That should be a comment.

Comment: How so? Cause its not spoon feeding? I give all the right tools to actually complete the task. Should any answer that is not a complete solution be a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Use `explode()`.

```
$fn = fopen("test.txt","r") or die("fail to open file");

while($row = fgets($fn)) {
  $content = explode( ";", $row);
  echo '<tr>' . $content . '<tr />';
}

fclose( $fn );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents), [explode](http://php.net/function.explode), and [implode](http://php.net/function.implode) to do this pretty easily:

```
$data = file_get_contents('file.txt');
$semi = explode(";", $data);
foreach($semi AS $row)
{
    $td = explode(",", $row);
    echo '<tr><td>' . implode('</td><td>', $td) . '</td></tr>';
}
```